# How to use default document preview callout popup in custom webpart?

Tags: 2013, document-library, visual-web-part, callouts

I have a custom webpart which gets each document's information from document library. I have created HTML table to show all the data in like **document name**, **Author**, **Created by**, **Modified by**, etc.

Now I want to open the callout popup on hover of document name. I want same functionality as shown in below image.

[image]

I need **all the document information** mentioned in above image in my custom webpart code.

Please help me by providing **JS or C# code behind solution** by which i can achieve it in my webpart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WopiFrame.aspx to open document in iframe.

I achieved this functionality in office 365 SharePoint because by default office 365 provide office web apps.

I generate iframe with jquery with below code

```
<div class='doc-online'>
    <iframe style='width:100%;' src='"  + SiteRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={" + guid + "}&action=interactivepreview ' width='400px' height='252px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This code simply shows the URL (Page) in iFrame. It is not opening callout popup. Can you please provide me the entire code which you tried? I want the callout popup in click event (HTML href).